# iOS 7.1 iPod 5th generation request for the state of beacon and ranging not happening

Tags: core-location, ibeacon, ios7.1, clregion

With the update of iOS 7.1 there is much changes in the ibeacon API for requesting, ranging beacon in the background even when app is killed or not launched, here are some of the things i observed as per the ranging for the beacons , in iPod 5th gen running with iOS 7.1

```
didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

doen't get called, but where as i run the same code in iPhone5 with 7.1 all the methods were getting called, its kind of a weird behaviour i'm facing,

http://www.proxima.io/blog/posts/2014-03-12-ios-7-1-ibeacon-tech-deep-dive/

as per the above link , it gives me something like there is not much update about ibeacon for the iOS7.1 in iPod 5th generation

Does any one faced this kind of same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you wait up to 15 minutes to get a call to `didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region` before you conclude it does not work.  On some devices, detection cash take that long.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html).  Do not expect calls to be received on both devices in a similar time frame.  One may be fast and the other slow based on model and internal state.

Other tips: try rebooting both devices to put them in the same state, and verify the problem persists.  Avoid running other iBeacon or Bluetooth apps simultaneously, as this can affect your test results.  I do not have access to an iPod for testing, but I know other folks report (including those at the page you reference) that iPods work fine with these APIs